# Can I run SSRS custom code on the same data source/query session as the report datasets?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am doing some per process authentication and I want to authenticate with the DB before the datasets are done.

The OnInit function does run before the datasets but does it on a different process/connection.

Can I somehow attach to the connection that the datasets are going to use?

EDIT: I am making reports for use in Report Manager.

Comment: We need more information - are you making reports for use in Report Manager, are you using Sharepoint, is this a Report Viewer control?

Comment: Thanks, I added using Report Manager to the post.